# Custom UITabeViewCell not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I need help in custom `UITableViewCell`

I am having two custom cells created in which I am checking my Question type using DTO.
If its is MCQ then load `QuizMCQTableViewCell` or if it is MRQ then load `QuizMRQTableViewCell`.

Here is my code below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[self.currentQuestionDTO type] isEqualToString:@"MCQ"])
    {
        QuizMCQTableViewCell *customcell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:optionCellIdentifier];
        if (customcell == nil)
        {
            customcell = [[[QuizMCQTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:optionCellIdentifier] autorelease];

        }else
        {
            UIImageView* MRQIV=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"]];
            customcell.checkBoxImgV.image = MRQIV.image;
            customcell.cellTextLbl.text = @"Hello";
        }
        return customcell;
    }

    if ([[self.currentQuestionDTO type] isEqualToString:@"MRQ"])
    {
        QuizMRQTableViewCell *customcell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:optionCellIdentifier];
        if (customcell == nil)
        {
            customcell = [[[QuizMRQTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:optionCellIdentifier] autorelease];

        }else
        {
            UIImageView* MRQIV=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]];
            customcell.radioBoxImgV.image = MRQIV.image;
            customcell.cellTextLbl.text = @"Hi";

        }
        return customcell;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

What I am facing problem is that,
When My tableView loaded then very first Question type is `MCQ`
so it goes for first cell, but didn't display anything, as I wrote the code in else loop of `if (customcell == nil)` 
So this is my first issue, why not text is set to hello.
But it work when I write my code in if loop.

and my second issue is,
When my code for type `MCQ` is in `if (customcell == nil)` 
When I load second question type `MRQ` my app get crash saying following error

```
-[QuizMCQTableViewCell radioBoxImgV]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

what I am doing wrong.
Please help.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem `Question type is MCQ so it goes for first cell, but didn't display anything`. Is that if you don't have the cells added in a `UITableView` inside a xib/sotryboard. The `dequeCell` will return `nil` so the `else` block won't be executed, this will result in empty display.

Second, `unrecognized selector` means that the property/method 'radioBoxImgV' doesn't exist on the object of `QuizMCQTableViewCell`. This is because you are using the same cell identifier for both cell types so the table view will return a cell of type `QuizMCQTableViewCell`. Crate two identifiers, one for first cell and one for second cell type.

Third, if you are using ARC, please remove the `autorelease` form the alloc/init.

Forth, **NEVER EVER EVER RETURN `nil` from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`**

Comment: Hi
if I used different identifier still it crashed
I am not using ARC not stroyboard, all done programatically
what may be issue behind crash

Comment: Got the answer, 
I was using different cell identifier but with same NSString

Comment: Thanks all,
@AndrewMonshizadeh & danypata :- Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason there is no text is that you are putting the set up code for the cells inside the `else` clause. The `if (cell == nil)` is used to determine if the `tableView` was able to dequeue an existing cell. If not you need to create one. Either way you then will want to set up the cell. So, if you move the set up code outside the else, you should see the behavior you expect.